# How to send a file to openhsift?

Tags: android, openshift

I have an Android app which saves data locally to a text file (det.txt). I also have a web application with php 5.3 on Openshift. Now I need to upload the text file to the web app on Openshift.

Here is the code which I use to upload the file:

```
try {
    String postReceiverUrl = "http://alldata-mylocation.rhcloud.com";

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

    File file = new File(detail);

    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
    httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    HttpResponse  response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
}
```

And here is the php code i pushed to the Openshift application:

```
<?php
    if($_FILES) {
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        $fileContents =  file_get_contents($file["tmp_name"]);
        print_r($fileContents);
    }
?>
```

But when I run my application, I find the default Openshift application page though I expected to see the file I uploaded. I also tried to specify the exact php file location in the url, but that also didn't work.

```
String postReceiverUrl = "http://alldata-mylocation.rhcloud.com/alldata_receiver.php";
```

Is there anything I am missing here? Or what else should I do/use to make this work?

I appreciate all thoughts you have. I'm a newbie with Openshift, so please don't hesitate to give me any hint.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you can see your page you uploaded in your web browser?  If it doesn't work there, it won't work when android tries to connect to it either.  Make sure you did not get any git push errors when you uploaded your code.

Comment: The problem was in the php script code. Thank you anyway.